# How to get sum by each factor level?

Tags: r

I have filtered data and one of the columns has 5 factor levels and I want to get sum for each of the factor level.

I am using the below code

```
levels(df_Temp$ATYPE)
[1] "a"  "b" "c"  "d"   "Unknown"
```

I am using the below code

```
cast(df_Temp,ATYPE~AFTER_ADM, sum, value = "CHRGES")
```

but the output I am getting is as below

```
  ATYPE 0          1
1 a     0 2368968.39
2 b     0 3206567.47
3 c     0   19551.19
4 e     0 2528688.12
```

I want to all the factor levels and sum as "0" for those missing data of factors level.

So the desired output is

```
  ATYPE 0          1
1 a     0 2368968.39
2 b     0 3206567.47
3 c     0   19551.19
4 d     0          0
5 e     0 2528688.12
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: Try `xtabs(CHRGES ~ ATYPE + AFTER_ADM, df_Temp)`

Comment: `cast(df,ATYPE~AFTER_ADM, sum, value = "CHRGES", add.missing = TRUE) ` is the command using `reshape`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(CHRGES ~ ATYPE + AFTER_ADM, subset(df_Temp, ATYPE != "e"))
#   AFTER_ADM
#ATYPE           0           1
#    a  0.00000000 -5.92270971
#    b -1.68910431  0.05222349
#    c -0.26869311  0.16922669
#    d  1.44764443 -1.59011411
#    e  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df_Temp <- data.frame(ATYPE = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE),
    AFTER_ADM = sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE), CHRGES = rnorm(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `dplyr`. First I created an example dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(letters[1:5], 1e3, replace = T)
x[x == "e"] <- "Unknown"
y <- sample(1:100, 1e3, replace = T)
df1 <- data.frame(ATYPE = factor(x), AFTER_ADM = y)
df1$AFTER_ADM[df1$ATYPE == "Unknown"] <- NA

head(df1, 10)
     ATYPE AFTER_ADM
1        b        28
2        d        60
3        c        17
4  Unknown        NA
5  Unknown        NA
6        a        48
7        c        78
8  Unknown        NA
9        c         7
10       c        45
```

And then use `group_by` and summarise to get the sum and the counts. I was not sure if you would want the counts for the factor levels but it is easy to take out if you are not interested:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ATYPE) %>%
  summarise(sum_AFTER_ADM = sum(AFTER_ADM, na.rm = T),
            n_ATYPE = n())
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  ATYPE   sum_AFTER_ADM n_ATYPE
  <fct>           <int>   <int>
1 a               10363     198
2 b               11226     206
3 c                9611     203
4 d                9483     195
5 Unknown             0     198
```

Comment: worked well, but I used one line code `xtabs(CHRGES ~ ATYPE + AFTER_ADM, df_Temp)` as my final code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Using count and complete from the two packages will help solve your problem.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    #using iris as toy data
    iris2 <- iris %>% 
             filter(Species != "setosa")

    #count data and then fill n with 0 
    ir3 <- count(iris2, Species) %>% 
        complete(Species, fill = list(n =0))
```

Comment: worked well, but I used one line code `xtabs(CHRGES ~ ATYPE + AFTER_ADM, df_Temp)` as my final code. thank you